# How to handle recursion error and prevent jupyter notebook kernel from dying?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to parse website with BeautifulSoup 4 and then write the desired information into yaml file. The website I am parsing is Protein Data Bank,I store html address of each target structure in my directory. I did it many times in my previous research and with even more data (parsing to get more information at once, etc.), however now it returns error **"RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object"**.
I tried to fix this error with `sys.setrecursionlimit(50000)`. I tried set several different numbers, but each time my **jupyter notebook kernel died**. Thus, this didnt work for me.

Can anyone help me with some suggestions where can be the problem and any ways how to fix it, please?
I use jupyter notebook. Weird for me is, that I used to use the same code with even more data parsing and more information extracting and it worked...but not there is problem.
Can it be somehow connected with internal memory? Maybe lack of internal memory?

There is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import yaml


PDB_ID = "1J5A, 1JZX, 1JZY, 1JZZ, 1K01, 1ML5, 1NKW, 1NWX, 1NWY, 1SM1, 1VVJ,...") #etc.,there is cca 110 of these files/websites -however in my previous research I use exact same amount and it worked
PDB_input = PDB_ID.split(", ")

for ID in PDB_input:
    dir_path = "/Documents/DATA/{}/" .format(ID)
    datafile = dir_path + "{}.html" .format(ID)
    
    with open(datafile) as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup("".join(f.readlines()), "html.parser")

        rna_a = soup.find("td", text="23S rRNA")
        rna_b = soup.find("td", text="23S RIBOSOMAL RNA")
        rna_c = soup.find("td", text="23S RRNA")
        rna_d = soup.find("td", text="23S ribosomal RNA")
        rna_e = soup.find("td", text="23s RNA")
        rna_f = soup.find("td", text="23S ribsomal RNA")
        rna_g = soup.find("td", text="23S Ribosomal RNA")
        rna_h = soup.find("td", text="50S 23S RIBOSOMAL RNA")
        rna_i = soup.find("td", text="RIBOSOMAL 23S RNA")
        rna_j = soup.find("td", text="LSU rRNA")
        
    desired_info = {}
    if rna_a:
        rna_23S_chain = rna_a.next_sibling.contents[0]
    elif rna_b:
        rna_23S_chain = rna_b.next_sibling.contents[0]
    elif rna_c:
        rna_23S_chain = rna_c.next_sibling.contents[0]
    elif rna_d:
        rna_23S_chain = rna_d.next_sibling.contents[0]
    elif rna_e:
        rna_23S_chain = rna_e.next_sibling.contents[0]
    elif rna_f:
        rna_23S_chain = rna_f.next_sibling.contents[0]
    elif rna_g:
        rna_23S_chain = rna_g.next_sibling.contents[0] 
    elif rna_h:
        rna_23S_chain = rna_h.next_sibling.contents[0]
    elif rna_i:
        rna_23S_chain = rna_i.next_sibling.contents[0]
    elif rna_j:
        rna_23S_chain = rna_j.next_sibling.contents[0]
    else:
        print("{} id missing 23S rRNA alternative name" .format(ID))
        
    desired_info["rRNA_23S"] = rna_23S_chain
    
    yaml_file = dir_path + "{}.yaml" .format(ID)
    with open(yaml_file, "w") as outfile:
        yaml.dump(desired_info, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

Comment: In your own words, why do you think the recursion occurs? When you look at the stack trace, what part of the code seems to be recursing? I'm guessing it's in `yaml.dump`, right? So - what happened when you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: Yes, recursion problem seems to be in `yaml.dump` but still cant figure it out as `sys.setrecursionlimit()` didnt work for my jupyter notebook (kernel always die). I am not very experienced user of bs4 and yaml, I used it just a few times.

Comment: Think about what YAML is for. Can you think of a reason why the code for creating YAML from a data structure might recurse *infinitely*? (Hint: what is the reason for it to recurse at all?) Now, what happens when you read the documentation? Do you see anything intended to safeguard against that? Do you see a warning about fixing it yourself? Anything relevant?